# User data adquistion in tizen javascript watchface

Tags: javascript, tizen-web-app

I am developing a samsung gear watchface in tizen studio with javascript
I need to get some user data in order to make the watchface work properly (the birthdate in this case) but I dont know how, because if I add a select field in the main html watchface page, it dows not work.
I have also tried with a button that user click and I show a javascript alert prompt but also the button click does not work

Answer (score 0):

One Possibility is It's working, but the placement is outside the watchface View Port.

Run As > Tizen Web Simulator Application

To Check the UI and placement of your input component.

Additional:

Watchfaces show/display information like Time, Power, Sensor Data, Weather, etc. There could also be some Shortcuts (links) to Apps/Features for User.

But, The Watchfaces aren't meant to receive Input text / Dropdowns / CheckLists from User.